# JQuery Mobile Open Video link inside page

Tags: video, jquery-mobile, youtube, html5-video

I am using JQuery Mobile version 1.1.1

I have a list of links when link to youTube videos.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="link to youtube video">See Video</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that when it opens the video page I cannot get back to the page as there's no Back button and it's no longer inside a JQM page.

How can I open it so that it either has a back button to return to the page of has a way of closing so I can return to the app without restarting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using the IFRAME embed method from YouTube:

It can be as easy as setting up an `<iframe>` like this:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But you can utilize the YouTube API as well, see these docs for more info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your
>   website and control the player using JavaScript. Unlike the Flash and
>   JavaScript player APIs, which both involve embedding a Flash object on
>   your web page, the IFrame API posts content to an  tag on your
>   page. This approach provides more flexibility than the previously
>   available APIs since it **allows YouTube to serve an HTML5 player rather
>   than a Flash player for mobile devices that do not support Flash.**
>
> *Src: The above link*

Comment: Where does the iframe exist in the DOM? Are you adding it dynamically, or should it already exist and then you set the src attribute using jquery? Is the iframe inside a dialog that's being opened by the link?

Comment: **1)** Wherever you want your user to see it. **2)** Either will work. **3)** When I've done this, I just placed the IFRAME in the `data-role="content"` section of the page and set it's width to 100% (you can keep the aspect ratio if you adjust the height on `window.resize`).

Answer (score 0):

You can have an embedded video player in an `HTML` page using the new [`<video>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp) `HTML5` tag.

Answer (score 0):

@Jasper is correct that using the iframe embed is the best way to play a video from a mobile site. What was not discussed is what else is involved. Here's a great demo of the new popup functionality in jquery mobile 1.2.0 (as of Oct. 2012):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html